# Inverted number triangle in php

Tags: php

I'm currently trying out PHP and I'm doing some exercises a friend told me but I can't seem to make the following:

```
98765
8765
765
65
5
```

I already made the following code:

```
<?php

for ($a = 9; $a >= 5; $a–-) {
    for ($b = 1; $b <= $a; $b++) {
        echo $a;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Any tips / fixes?

Comment: Everything correct! expect that in the inner loop you want to loop from `$a` down to the minimum value, which in your case is `5`. Means in the first iteration from 9 to 5, then 8 to 5, ...

Comment: Glad to hear that my code was correct but I'm sorry for even asking but I did not completely understand your answer so could U maybe explain a bit further @Rizier123? since I'm pretty new to PHP:$
And for some reason it shows the following output:
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999
999999999

Comment: Remove everything in your loop, means the inner second loop and the echo statement. Then just put `echo $a . "<br>";` in there. You will see that you print the first number of every line from your expected output. So you will then see that with your inner loop you just want to loop from `$a` down to 5 and print all those numbers between `$a` and 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed it by creating the following code:

```
for ($a = 0; $a <= 9; $a++) {
    for ($b = 9 - $a; $b >= 5; $b--) {
        echo $b;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Thanks for at least answering guys!

Comment: This will give you a bunch of `<br>`s at the end of your triangle, try a different integer in `$a <= 9;` - see answer by Mistery

Comment: It seems like you still miss the understanding of what is happening. It might help if you just take a simple piece of paper and write down how each variable changes each iteration and what exactly happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
    <?php 
   for($a=9; $a >= 5; $a--) {
    for ($b=$a; $b >= 5; $b--) {
        echo $b;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: You can use the special character "\n" or <br> as you wish.

Comment: Maybe hare should be `<br/>` because we need to take a line break .

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    function print_triangle($start, $count) {
        for ($a = 0; $a < $count; $a++) {
            for ($b = $start - $a; $b > $start - $count; $b--) {
                echo $b;
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }

    print_triangle(9, 5);

?>
```

Hope it helps!